# How to read the xml from one function which is loaded by another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Below is the scenario:
The xmlDoc I am trying to read in function B is declared globally.

```
    function main()
{
   ...
   A(input xml);
...
B(other inputs);
}

function A(XML_input)
{
...
    var xmlDoc = FLEXWIN.GetData.dsoValidator1Resp.XMLDocument;
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(XML_input.xml);
}

function B(some other input)
{
    // I want to use the xmlDoc.xml here.. But its content is blank.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
    var xmlDoc = A(input_xml);
    B(xmlDoc, other_inputs);
}

function A(XML_input) {
    var xmlDoc = FLEXWIN.GetData.dsoValidator1Resp.XMLDocument;
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(XML_input.xml);

    return xmlDoc;
}

function B(xmlDoc, other_input) {
    //Etc.
}
```